# How to write string to memoryview?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, memoryview

I want to write a `bytearray` type into a `memoryview` type. What I tried:

```
my_memory_view = memoryview(b'hello')
new_byte_string = bytearray(b'world')
my_memory_view = new_byte_string
```

but it returned:

```
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

I know that it is possible to write into memoryview via:

```
my_memory_view[0] = 12  #Changes first byte
```

Is there a way to insert the values of the `bytearray` automatically into `memoryview`?

#### Edit:

I made a mistake: the error is not `AttributeError` the problem occurs because the type changes,  but in my package I use(`shared_memory`)
`AttributeError` will be shown.

Comment: You can't write to a memoryview over an immutable object.

Comment: Your code works fine when I run it. There are no errors and afterwards a `print(my_memory_view)` displays: `bytearray(b'world')`.  Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Also, while your code is wrong and doesn't work, it doesn't produce the error message you claim. (Instead, it silently does something different from what you wanted - it just reassigns a variable instead of writing into the memoryview.)

Comment: After the `my_memory_view = new_byte_string`, the `type(my_memory_view)` is `<class 'bytearray'>` — it's no longer a `memoryview`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't write into your memoryview, because your memoryview is a view of a bytes object, which is immutable.

If you had a writable memoryview, such as `memoryview(bytearray(b'hello'))`, you could do

```
your_memoryview[:] = whatever
```

to write the contents of `whatever` into the underlying memory.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytearray-objects), "`bytearray` objects are a **mutable** counterpart to `bytes` objects" (emphasis mine).

Comment: @martineau: Yeah, but `memoryview(b'hello')` isn't a memoryview of a bytearray. If it *was*, then you could write into it.

Comment: The code in the question is trying to write a bytearray into a memoryview over a bytes object, not write a bytes object into a memoryview over a bytearray.

Comment: ok thanks to all of you how helped at this question. This helps me a lot.